# Calling child overrided method from parent

Tags: objective-c

I'm having trouble finding out the way to implenent something similar to abstract class in Objective-C.

I don't actually care about restricting to use my base class without subclassing it, all I want is this:
I want to have class A (parent/base/abstract) which has method something like `- (void)makeRequest` and I want to subclass it in classes B,C,D etc and have methods like `- (id)getCachedResult` that are being called from class' A method. So basically I want class A to implement some base logic and I want it's subclasses to modify some details and parts of this base logic.

Sounds like a trivia, but I can't put my finger on the way to implement such pattern in Objective-C.

UPDATE:

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
@interface A : NSObject

- (void)makeRequest;
- (NSString *)resultKey;

@property (strong) NSMutableDictionary * result;

@end

@implementation A

- (void)makeRequest
{
    self.result[self.resultKey] = @"Result";
}

- (NSString *)resultKey
{
    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:NSInternalInconsistencyException
                                   reason:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ should be overrided in subclass", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)]
                                 userInfo:nil];
    return nil;
}

@end

/////////////////////////////

@interface B : A

@end

@implementation B

- (NSString *)resultKey
{
    return @"key";
}

@end
```

When I'm creating instance of class B and trying to call it's method `- (void)makeRequest` I'm getting exception, and that's pretty obvious. What I want is a way to correctly design my classes for the same purpose.

Comment: That is rather trivial. It's the basic concept of subclassing. Where exactly is your problem? You should provide some concrete example of code and describe the problem with it. When you do everythnig right - and there are not many chances of making mistakes - then it shoudl simply work the way you describe it.

Comment: @HermannKlecker, Ok, I'll update my question to be more specific about where am I having trouble.

Comment: You should declare `resultKey` in B's interface.

Comment: I don't see why `resultKey` of `A`?  is invoked and not `resultKey` of `B`. AFAIK everythin is ok so far. Could you add that very code where you create the instance of `B` and call its `makeRequest`?

Comment: What exception to you actually get? The one that you are thowing or one that may be a result of `result` not being initialized or a key accessed that does not exist. BTW, result is an array, not a dictionary. You should use numeric indices. Plus you shoud use the 'old fashioned' objectAtIndex: method to access indexes. However I assume, if you want key-value-pairs, that you are better off with an NSDictionary. In any case your array or dictionary needs to be initialized and allocated and of course filled with the data that you want to fetch.

Comment: @Matthias, you're my savior! That did the trick, thanks a lot! Mind adding answer to the question so I could mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested: You should declare `resultKey` in B's interface.  :-)

Comment: As a matter of style, maybe. But method declarations in interfaces have no impact on runtime behaviour. Whatever fixed this, it wasn't that.

Comment: @ChrisDevereux: I disagree. At runtime, the message is send to the "lowest" (in class hierarchy) object with the requested **selector** (not method). The compiler generates selectors from interface. It can also be done at runetime, but this has to be done explicitly. In the case of the OP's question, no selector of class B is known and thus, the method of the super class is called.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtHowMessagingWorks.html

Comment: @ChrisDevereux: your link describes exactly the same what I have written. Next time, read more carefully.

Comment: "When a message is sent to an object, the messaging function follows the object’s isa pointer to the class structure where it looks up the method selector in the dispatch table". An instance of B's isa pointer points to B. Implementing the method is sufficient for the dispatch table to return B's implementation for `resultKey`. This does not require a declaration in the @interface. So changing the interface declaration of B has no effect on the runtime behaviour of B.

Comment: Please note the word **selector**. As you may know, the selector is not the method resp. the implementation. If you don't believe me, try OP's code.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that choice of words matters here. Perhaps we're talking past each other somehow. Either way, I think you should edit your answer to explain why you think this suggestion works.

Comment: OP's code works without modification for me. But I'm not going to discuss this further.

Comment: @Matthias the selector is not coupled to any implementation and certainly not bound to any class's implementation at compile time...